# How to change the MainAxisAlignment of a single element inside a Column

Tags: flutter

I have a Column widget like this :

```dart
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('Month',
          style: theme.textTheme.subtitle1,),
          Icon(Icons.trending_up_rounded,
            size: 30, color: Color(0xffe8407a)),
          Text('+5.5kg',
          style: theme.textTheme.subtitle2)
        ],
      )
```

it renders like this [image]

I just want to change the alignment of the Icon, so its vertically centered, but keep the Text aligned to the start, something like align-self or justify-self in CSS.

How can I do this in flutter?

Comment: You want **trending_up_rounded** icon exact center of the month and weight? can you share image what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by two way

first, wrap `Icon` with `Center` widget

or wrap `Icon` with `Row` and set `Row` `MainAxisAlignment` to center

Answer (score 2):

Wrap needed widget with Align widget.

```
Align(alignment:Alignment.Center,  
Icon(Icons.trending_up_rounded,
        size: 30, color: Color(0xffe8407a)),)
```